# Date Parameter Validation in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

How can i validate date parameters in a pentaho report designer.I am using "fromDate"  and "ToDate " parameters in my report/prpt.Because if i am selecting particular date range  i will get that particular date ranging values only..It is working fine...
  But if anyone is selecting date range like " FromDate > ToDate " i want to show some notifications like " wrong date selection  "  like dat..

Is it possible in Pentaho Report Designer? Or by using  some java SCript?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context? I don't seem to understand your question.

But try to use the IF formula to your parameter (since I believe you are using it as a field in your report) to render the value to be "Wrong date selection" if the start date is greater than the end date or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

In a Pentaho report designer, take a label for validation and edit a value in the attribute tab as -

```
=IF([FromDate ]>[ToDate];"'ToDate' should be greater than or equal to 'FromDate '";
IF([FromDate ]>TODAY();"'FromDate ' should be less than or equal to 'current date'";""))
```

Hope this answer helps.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqfB3.png)